# Как подключить сразу два файла .css?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Мне нужно подключить два файла .css к .html странице. При попытке подключить сразу два файла с помощью `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home_page.css">`, автоматически выбирается тот, который был подключен последним. Можно ли подключать два файла сразу, и как?

Comment: Прописать тег link два раза с нужными путями.

Comment: @andreymal, это не поможет, если в файлах одни и те же классы :)

Comment: Как именно ты пытался подключить? Какое содержимое этих файлов? Почему ты думаешь, что выбирается только последний?

Answer (score 1):

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/first.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/second.css">
```